# What is the Greek etymology for "-on" in words like "proton" and "neutron"?

Tags: etymology, suffixes, greek

Google says "proton" is from "protos" and "-on" ("first" + "being"), or "πρῶτος" and "?". What is the "-on" in Greek, is it "ὤν" or "ἐν" or something?

Comment: But this is an English site, not a Greek site …

Comment: Ancient Greek is normally treated at https://latin.stackexchange.com or the etymology can also be asked at https://linguistics.stackexchange.com

Comment: Folks, this is an English etymology question alright.

Comment: As John Lawler observes in a comment beneath the accepted answer, the '-on' suffix in electron (and in argon) is '-ον' (omicron nu).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

***-on,*** from ion, Greek present participle of ienai (go)

[Electron:](https://www.etymonline.com/word/electron?ref=etymonline_crossreference)

> coined 1891 by Irish physicist George J. Stoney (1826-1911) from electric + ***-on, as in ion***.

***ion (n.):***

> 1834, introduced by English physicist and chemist Michael Faraday (suggested by the Rev. William Whewell, English polymath), ***coined from Greek ion, neuter present participle of ienai "go,"*** from PIE root *ei- "to go." So called because ions move toward the electrode of opposite charge.

(Etymonline)

Comment: Can you please write it in greek script, that's the main thing I am looking for.

Comment: @LancePollard - see here https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E1%BC%B0%CE%AD%CE%BD%CE%B1%CE%B9

Comment: How about for the `on` part specifically, is it omega v or what?

Comment: No, it's omicron nu. The Greek -on singular neuter is cognate to the Latin -um singular neuter; the plural neuter for both languages is -a (alpha in Gk).

Comment: And here I thought electron was already the Greek word for amber

Comment: @LancePollard If it's super-important that the answer uses Greek script, this really doesn't look like a question about English.

Comment: The Greek words are [ἰόν](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E1%BC%B0%CF%8C%CE%BD) the neuter present participle of [ἰέναι](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ἰέναι) *(to go)* and [εἶμι](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%CE%B5%E1%BC%B6%CE%BC%CE%B9) *(I go)*

Comment: So is "on" taken to mean "gone", since that is the past participle of "go"?

Comment: @TylerH - “coined from Greek ion, neuter *present participle* of ienai "

Comment: @user067531 Sorry, which is it? present or past? Your second quote conflicts with your own wording at the top of the answer.

Comment: This is false.  πρῶτον
and other words ending in -ον
have, generally, "nothing" to do with ἴον.

Answer (score 5):

Here's the Oxford English Dictionary's etymology for the ending -*on*:

> *-on* (in *electron* n.2, itself after earlier *ion* n.), reinforced in both senses by *-ον* as a termination of Greek neuter nouns and adjectives and their derivatives, and (especially in sense 2) perhaps by ancient Greek *ὄν* being (compare -*ont* comb. form).

Context:

- "Sense 2" is in words like [*chronon*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chronon), [*virion*](https://bio.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Microbiology/Book%3A_Microbiology_(Boundless)/9%3A_Viruses/9.1%3A_Overview_of_Viruses/9.1B%3A_Nature_of_the_Virion), and [*codon*](https://www.nature.com/scitable/definition/codon-155/) which are "entities conceived of as discrete or basic units".
- -*ont* is used in words like [planont](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/planont).

Answer (score 4):

Michael Quinion, *Ologies and Isms: Word Beginnings and Endings* (Oxford, 2002) breaks its coverage the suffix -*on* into two entries, starting with this one:

> **-on<sup>1</sup>** *Subatomic particles or quanta; molecular units.* {Originally from *electron*, probably from the ending of *ion* and influenced by Greek *on*, being.}
>
> An electron a a stable subatomic particle with a negative charge. On its model, **-on** has become the dominant ending with which to label elementary particles and groups of such particles (for another see **-tron**); ...

Quinion then lists English examples of this line of derivation from the subcategories of particles (*proton*, *meson*, *baryon*), quanta (*photon*, *graviton*, *phonon*), and molecular biology (*codon*, *intron*, *operon*). But that doesn't exhaust the universe of Greek-derived English words ending in *-on*. Quinion follows with this entry:

> **-on<sup>2</sup>** *Inert gases.* {The Greek neuter ending *-on*.}
>
> Argon was the first of the inert gases to be discovered; its name was taken from Greek, the neuter of *argos*, idle, from *a-* without, plus *ergon*, work. Others were named in imitation: ***neon*** (Greek, literally 'something new', neuter of the adjective *neos*), ***krypton*** (Greek *krupton*, neuter of *kruptos*, hidden); ***xenon*** (Greek, neuter of *xenos*, stranger); ***radon*** (from *radium*).

*Merriam-Webster's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary* (2003) gives first-occurrence dates of 1891 for *electron* and 1894 (*argon*), 1898 (*neon*, *krypton*, and *xenon*), and 1918 (*radon*) for the inert gases. The odd gas out here is helium, which was named in 1872 and somehow avoided being retroactively renamed *helion*. As for *ion*, the possible inspiration for *electron*, it dates to 1834.

Whether the inert gas names starting in 1894 were influenced by the slightly earlier emergence of *electron* (in 1891) is a matter of conjecture, but as Quinion shows, the term *a-ergon* has solid etymological legitimacy in its own right—and the particulate sense of the *ion/electron* family of words is unmatched by the gases except under a very powerful microscope.

Answer (score 1):

-ον is the ending of most neütral adjectives (in the singular
nominative).  πρῶτος is masculine, πρῶτον is neütral.

The neütral present participle ὄν (being) of
εἶναι (to be) is
also
an adjective ending in -ον,
but plays no rôle in explaining the form 
πρῶτον.
Similarly with
ἴον (going), in spite of the accepted answer.